# Safari not displaying jssor slideshow image

Tags: css, cross-browser, jssor

I have a slideshow here: https://namibiabowhunting.com/vbook.html

All browsers except Safari show the images.

Inspecting the elements using Safari for Windows (v. 5.1.7) it seems that css and the images are loading correctly, but the images are not being displayed.

I also tried modifying the z-index of images, but that did not make a difference either.

Since there is no newer version of Safari for Windows available I do not know if this problem disappears with newer versions.

Any help in identifying the issue would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems you are using Fancybox, I would make sure all the plug-ins and dependencies are updated, test it on multiple devices, etc. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful, but without your code base, etc. it's difficult to tell.

Comment: @Ernie Actually it's all simple html files, so you can view the source and inspect on the website. JQuery and fancybox are updated to the newest version and work in all other browsers, including FF, Chrome and Edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the issue.

On your page you have a `<div>` structure with several divs being parents of the `<img>` tag that's not showing. While the `<img>` tag has its width and height set, and some parent `<div>` tags as well, it's still inside parent `<div>`'s that have `height: 0` either set or inherited, but have `overflow:hidden;` set. See in the inspector which div has 0 height, and set either it's `height: 100%;` or `min-height: 100%;` or delete `overflow:hidden;` and that should do it.

So either unset `overflow:hidden;` on `<div class="slideimg">` (on both y and x) or set height/min-height to 100% on the child of `<div id="jssor_1">` AND the child of that child.

Comment: Thanks. that was it. the problem was a bit more complicated because the jssor javascript inserted html and did not copy the classes. I had to hardcode the styles into the html elements.

Comment: Whatever works for you. Sometimes you can also use !important in your custom css to override the inline styling that's added even by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If inspecting element shows correct CSS and the images and you are 100% sure they should be there but aren't, you might have disabled displaying images in Safari itself. You can try another page if it shows images in Safari.

Anyway, if it indeed is a problem of Safari itself do the folowing -

1. Click the "Safari" menu in Safari and select "Preferences."
2. Click the "Appearance" icon.
3. See if you have "Display images when the page opens." checked and check if not, do check that.

If those settings aren't available, check if you don't have "Disable images" checked in the "Develop menu".

(Once I can comment, I'll actually simply ask in comments and edit this answer accordingly.)

(Also - you should provide a code snippet of the problematic part or similar for the future users. If the website in question stops working or changes, this question will no longer make sense and provide the information expected.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the images actaully show, except for that slideshow. If I knew where approximately the problem is I would also include code, but unfortunately I have no idea what the issue is.

Comment: I thought so - I'll try to figure something else out soon. Do you have access to any other Safari version, or a Mac version, to try if this issue persists through environments?

Comment: So I installed Windows under a virtual machine in Linux and the images indeed do not display in Safari there. I'll investigate more.